# Setup Github on Mac

Tags: git, web, github

Im looking for the easiest way to setup my Github to the mac.
I also would like it to be Gui based and not terminal based like with SourceTree.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is the best option.
  You have it all in there including internal git version if you need it.
- [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/)
  Another good choice
- [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) -
  Your GitHub workflow in one native app

As you can see they are much or more the same (Gui layout)

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you please specify the process of installation?

Comment: simply follow the steps on you selected software.

Comment: Each site has its own instructions.

Comment: I meant the process of setup and connecting SourceTree on the mac.

Comment: I recommend using sourcetree. simply download and install and its will setup anything automatically for you as default

Comment: Thanks For the Help!